# Python get objects in list with matching attributes

Tags: python, list, attributes, generator

I have a list of objects and need to get all objects that have the same value for one attribute to process them further.  Everything I have Googled and SO'd brings up already knowing the value I am looking for.  Instead, I just need the matches.  Say I have this

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

p1 = Person("mike", 28)
p2 = Person("joe", 28)
p3 = Person("nick", 27)
p4 = Person("Janet", 27)
people = [p1, p2, p3]
#need something like
matches = getMatches(people, "age")
print matches
[[Mike's object, Joe' Object], [Nick's object, Janet's object]]
```

I came up with this and it works, but seems kinda crappy to me

```
def getMatches(objs, attr):
    def Gen(objs, attr):
        used = [] #already searched for these...
        for obj in objs:
            a = getattr(obj, attr)
            if a not in used:
                yield [p for p in objs if getattr(p, attr) == a]
            used.append(a)
    gen = Gen(objs, attr)
    return [g for g in gen]
```

In my actual code, it makes a lot more sense to need this.  Can anyone help me clean this up or is there a standard function or way of accomplishing this already out there I just don't know about?

I appreciate the answers, ended up using groupby and being sure to sort them first.  This is the first time I have tried to write a generator.  If I may ask, what would make my code proper and pythonic, so to speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [operator.attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby
def getMatches(people, prop):
    people = sorted(people, key = attrgetter(prop))
    return [list(grp) for k, grp in groupby(people, attrgetter(prop))]

print getMatches(people, "age")
```

You can check the result like this

```
for group in getMatches(people, "age"):
    print [people.name for people in group]
```

**Output**

```
['mike', 'joe']
['nick', 'Janet']
```

Comment: Note that this _only_ works if the list of people is sorted by the key attribute (more specifically, if items with the same key are presented together).

Comment: @alexis Yup. You are correct :) I updated the answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def get_matches(objs, key):
    d = {}
    for obj in objs:
        d.setdefault(getattr(obj, key), []).append(obj)
    return d
```

after which [I added a `repr`]:

```
>>> get_matches(people, "age")
{27: [{'name': 'nick', 'age': 27}, {'name': 'Janet', 'age': 27}], 
 28: [{'name': 'mike', 'age': 28}, {'name': 'joe', 'age': 28}]}
```

One advantage this offers is that `groupby` acts by grouping by *contiguous* values.  If that's what you want, it's perfect.  Otherwise, you have to remember to sort by the key function first.  (The downside here is that it doesn't preserve the order of occurrence of the key values, although we could use `collections.OrderedDict` if we really cared.)